# continuous scrolling. AJAX, PHP, JAVASCRIPT, MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am actually creating a forum. So, there would be a "order by" dropdown box i.e a select tag in html. Where the user selects any order like by time or like, etc. An ajax function is called which dynamically brings content into the page from mysql database.

**Select menu**

```
<select name="orderby" onchange="showposts(this.value)">
<option value="1" selected>By Time</option>
<option value="2">By Genuine Count</option>
<option value="3">By Dubious Count</option>
</select>
```

**showposts function**

```
function showposts(str){

        orderby=str;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("postsdiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","showposts.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**Showposts.php page**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts order by date desc ";
$result = $connection->query($sql);
$username=$_SESSION['username'];

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<span id='postspan".$row['id']."' name='postspan".$row['id']."' >";
    echo "<span id='editspan".$row['id']."' name='editspan".$row['id']."' >";
    echo "-----------------------------------</br>";
    echo "-----------------------------------</br>";

    echo "Posted By: ".$row['user']."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
    echo "Time: ".$row['date']."</br>";
    echo "<span id=genuinecount".$row['id'].">Genuine Count: ".$row['genuine'].";        
    echo "<span id=dubiouscount".$row['id'].">Dubious Count: ".$row['dubious']."</span>";
    echo "</br>------------------------ </br>";
    echo "Subject: ".$row['subject']."</br>";

    echo "Post: ".$row['post'].'<br />';
```

}

**Problem**
    So, the problem here is, I want to use a continuous scroll option like the one which is used in facebook. All the javascripts and jquery libraries I saw use logic that when the user scrolls down to the page, the javascript then places some content after that. But, here I running a while loop which brings the data from database at a time. So, I couldn't implement the javascript code. So, is there any thing that I could do to achieve continuous scroll, like is there any possibility to break the while loop or retrieving entire data and display part by part or anything like that?

**javascript for scrolling**

```
function yhandler(){
    var wrap=document.getElementById('postsdiv');
    var contentheight=wrap.offsetHeight;
    var yoffset=window.pageYOffset;
    var y=yoffset+window.innerHeight;
    if(y>=contentheight){
        showposts();
}
}
window.onscroll=yhandler();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into MySQL `LIMIT`. The limit function takes 2 input variables, start and length. With these 2 variables you can create a paging system; that would go something among the lines of:

**showposts function**

```
//Add a global variable to save the current page:
var currentPage = 0;
var currentType = 0;

function showposts(str){
    //ALL PREVIOUS CODE, UNCHANGED

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("postsdiv").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    if(str != undefined){
        currentType = str; //save the current type for later use
        document.getElementById("postsdiv").innerHTML = "";
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","showposts.php?q="+currentType+"&p="+currentPage,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**Showposts.php page**

```
<?php
$currentPage = intval($_GET['p']);
$numPerPage = 30; //change this to the number of items you want each page

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts order by date desc LIMIT ".($currentPage * $numPerPage).", ".$numPerPage;
$result = $connection->query($sql);
$username=$_SESSION['username'];

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<span id='postspan".$row['id']."' name='postspan".$row['id']."' >";
    echo "<span id='editspan".$row['id']."' name='editspan".$row['id']."' >";
    echo "-----------------------------------</br>";
    echo "-----------------------------------</br>";

    echo "Posted By: ".$row['user']."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
    echo "Time: ".$row['date']."</br>";
    echo "<span id=genuinecount".$row['id'].">Genuine Count: ".$row['genuine']."</span>";        
    echo "<span id=dubiouscount".$row['id'].">Dubious Count: ".$row['dubious']."</span>";
    echo "</br>------------------------ </br>";
    echo "Subject: ".$row['subject']."</br>";

    echo "Post: ".$row['post'].'<br />';
}
?>
```

Now you need to detect when a user has scrolled to the bottom of the page, then call the following function:

```
function nextPage(){
    currentPage++;

    showposts();
}
```

Comment: why are you sending currenttype from js function?

Comment: Whoops a slight type, that should be str. Save that so the next pages loaded are loaded with the same type / q.

Comment: Sorry but actually i'm bit confused and trying to figure out. Could you wait for while and return to you..?

Comment: the showposts() takes input str, which comes from on select method of the drop down list. So, how can I call showposts() without str in your function nextpage()?

Comment: You can call a javascript function without the input, it will put 'undefined' for all the input variables. That's why i am checking if str != undefined, if its not than the function is called from the onChange, and we save the type for later use (e.g. when scrolling).

Comment: ok... I have implemented your code, but I don't know where I'm going wrong.. the java script function I used for scrolling is:function yhandler(){
    var wrap=document.getElementById('postsdiv');
    var contentheight=wrap.offsetHeight;
    var yoffset=window.pageYOffset;
    var y=yoffset+window.innerHeight;
    if(y>=contentheight){
        showposts();
    }
}
window.onscroll=yhandler();

Comment: I put this code in my question edit. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Does the function work? Place alert(1); at the beginning of the showposts() function. Also; you have one to many `"` in your php script, replace `.$row['genuine']."; ` with `.$row['genuine']; `

Comment: alert is comming.. but nothing is working.. I dont know where i went wrong.

Comment: Could you alert the `xmlhttp.responseText` inside the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange ` function, what does that give?

Comment: It is giving.. entire php code which is echoed in show posts file

Comment: the div should be placed inside the while loop right..?

Comment: No you would just place the #postsdiv somewhere on your page, where you want to display the rows / posts

Comment: could you please tell me the changes you have in the php file?

Comment: I opened and closed PHP so you shouldn't see the the entire php code, and changed `.$row['genuine'].";` to `.$row['genuine']."</span>";`

Comment: It is now echoing the php echoed html.. the quotes thing was actually a typo. Please ignore that.

Comment: another problem is whenever i change the order by option, it is appending with previous data, since we are appending the response text.

Comment: Are you getting any Javascript errors in the console? I have edited the showposts function to fix that problem.

Comment: I not getting any posts at all. the console is saying,"cannot read property offsetheight of null".

Comment: Where in your code are you using offsetHeight?? Please also include that code in your question, since the error is coming from there.

Comment: after placing the if(str!=undefined) condition above onreadystatechange function.. i am getting posts.. but i think the javascript is not working.

Comment: I have set numperpage=5, so im getting 5 posts but after scrolling.. nothing is happening

Comment: Change `var contentheight=wrap.offsetHeight;` to `var contentheight= document.getElementById('postsdiv').offsetHeight;`

Comment: Is the postsdiv actually on the page? Not in the showposts.php page but on the same page as the showposts function is? Please post where you have placed the `<div id="postsdiv"></div>`

Comment: yes..it is.. i just googled about the error. Its due to some loading problem. So, i echoed the javascript code in php just under the div. Now im not getting any error but again its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PDO class built into php and the query from the database will return all the rows as an array of stdclass objects.  Then use PDOStatement::fetchObject() to loop through the array

Answer (score 0):

As you are retrieving the data from server using JavaScript, why don't you put the view with the help of JavaScript instead of PHP.

Try using Asynchronous Javascript Call (AJAX) instead of XMLHttpRequest. This will help you to load data asynchronously which means that even if the the result coming form server take time you can still execute your other javascript codes.

With AJAX implemented, let say you want to fetch 10 Posts at one time, then after fetching first 10 posts, you can print the data for those 10 using JavaScript and simultaneously make a call for another 10.

Prepare a successCallBack function, where you will parse the data received and put that as required for your HTML. You will need to append the posts, so that when the next AJAX returns the result, that gets appended after the last post.

http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/ajax/

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is actually the native way in JavaScript to make an AJAX call, it is what jQuery uses for the $.ajax function.

Comment: I know this, but it provides a simple way of doing asynchronously, that is why I suggested this