# AJAX page reload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am creating a forum in which the posted user has option to delete his own posts. So, I am using ajax to send get request to delete a particular post and I am echoing null in place of the deleted post. The problem here is the post is getting deleted but the page is reloading after deletion which shouldn't happen as I am using ajax request. Can anyone help?

---

**PHP CODE TO DISPLAY THE POSTS(ONLY A PART)**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM classposts where branch='$branch' and joindate='$year' and class='$class'    order by".$orderby." desc";
$result = $connection->query($sql);
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<span id='postspan".$row['id']."' name='postspan".$row['id']."' >";
    echo "<span id='editspan".$row['id']."' name='editspan".$row['id']."' >";
    echo "-----------------------------------</br>";
    echo "-----------------------------------</br>";

    echo "Posted By: ".$row['user']."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
    if($username==$row['user']){
        echo "<a href='classwall.php' onclick='deletepost(".$row['id'].")' >DELETE POST</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";

    }
```

Ignore if any parenthesis are not matching as this is only a part of the code.

---

**javascript function which is called after delete link is clicked**

```
function deletepost(postid){
    var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the post?");
    if(r==true){
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

                document.getElementById("postspan"+postid).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","deletepost.php?pid="+postid,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }else{}
}
```

---

**deletepost.php page**

```
$pid=$_GET['pid'];
$query="delete from dubiousposts where id='$pid'";
$sql=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$query="delete from genuineposts where id='$pid'";
$sql=mysqli_query($connection,$query);

$query="delete from posts where id='$pid'";
$sql=mysqli_query($connection,$query);

if($result=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "";
}
```

Comment: After ajax call use `return false;` to stop reload.

Comment: Are `$branch`, `$year` and `$class` safe ? Because your `deletepost.php` page is not at all...

Comment: where should i exactly use return false; ?

Comment: @Brewal Sorry that was a typo. Please ignore that line.

Comment: I'm talking about sql injection here

Comment: GET requests should never be used for delete actions: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: @lonecoder you should return false in javascript function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given the ahref link to calsswall.php page that's why you goes to other page.

change

```
echo "<a href='classwall.php' onclick='deletepost(".$row['id'].")' >DELETE POST</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
```

to

```
echo "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='deletepost(".$row['id'].")' >DELETE POST</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
```

Comment: ya the page is not reloading now but showing an error at showposts page last if condition.Message: "Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given ".

Comment: You can't fetch data from delete query. You have to remove `if($result=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "";
}`

Comment: by the way what you want to do with this statement?

Comment: omg thank you very much.. its working.. Can you please give me your email id, i am having a few doubts regarding my project?

Comment: Sir, could you please answer this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27165317/continuous-scrolling-ajax-php-javascript-mysql

Comment: sure, let me check that

Comment: Sir Im having another doubt regarding editing the posts in the above script. But i couldn't post another question until 90 min, So can you give your contact info like mail id or something?

Comment: wait, I am looking in that question

Comment: sir if you could, please look into this one too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189265/edit-posts-ajax-php-javascript

Comment: for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189265/edit-posts-ajax-php-javascript replace your edit line with this code `echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="editpost('.$row["id"].',\''.$row["subject"].'\',\''.$row["post"].'\')" >EDIT1 </a></br>';`

Comment: yes sir i got answer for that.. but the above question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27165317/continuous-scrolling-ajax-php-javascript-mysql is not still answered by any one.