# edit posts AJAX, PHP, javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating a forum in which the users can edit their posts. I have no idea how to do that, but i tried something as follows:

---

**php code to show posts**

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<div class='postclass'>";
echo "<span id='postspan".$row['id']."' name='postspan".$row['id']."' >";
echo "<span id='editspan".$row['id']."' name='editspan".$row['id']."' >";

echo "</br>";

echo "Posted By: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <span class='bold'> ".$row['user']."</span>";
if($username==$row['user']){
    echo "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";

    echo "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='deletepost(".$row['id'].")' >DELETE </a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";

    echo "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='editpost(".$row['id'].",'".$row['subject']."','".$row['post']."')' >EDIT </a></br>";
    }else{
        echo "</br>";
}
```

---

**javascript function which is called when edit link is clicked**

```
function editpost(postid,subject,post){

    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

            document.getElementById("editspan"+postid).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","editpost.php?pid="+postid+"&subject="+subject+"&post="+post,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

---

**editpost.php page**

```
$pid=$_GET['pid'];
$subject=$_GET['subject'];
$post=$_GET['post'];
}else{
    $pid="";
    $subject="";
    $post="";
}
echo "<form method='POST' action='globalwall.php'>
    <p>Subject:
        <label for='subject'></label>
        <input type='text' name='subject' id='subject' value='".$subject."' />
    </br>
    </p>
    <p>Post: <br />
        <label for='post'></label>
        <textarea name='post' id='post' cols='45' rows='5' value='".$post."'></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type='submit' name='postbutton' id='postbutton' value='Edit' />
    </p>
</form>";
```

---

when i click the edit button nothing is happening. Even if i place an alert message in javascript function, it is also not popping up. Can anyone help please?

---

Comment: First replace your `echo "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='editpost(".$row['id'].",".$row['subject'].",".$row['post'].")' >EDIT </a></br>";` line with `echo "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='editpost(".$row['id'].",\"".$row['subject']."\",\"".$row['post']."\")' >EDIT </a></br>";`

Comment: Your generated code for edit looks invalid to me, check your generated code

Comment: @MIvanIsten Yes sir, now I'm getting the echoed form, but it is empty. But I want previously entered data in that form.

Comment: I see an `}else{` in your editpost.php, but what is the `if` ?

Comment: I have removed single quotes in the echoing form. Now i am getting subject's text but the post textarea is still empty. If i replacing value attribute with placeholder then the text is appearing. What should i do?

Comment: Update your question with actual code. And show the generated html too.

Comment: Got it sir, thank you very much. If you can put your first comment in answer, I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your

```
echo "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='editpost(".$row['id'].",".$row['subject'].",".$row['post'].")' >EDIT </a></br>";
```

line with

```
echo "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='editpost(".$row['id'].",\"".$row['subject']."\",\"".$row['post']."\")' >EDIT </a></br>";
```